# google translate on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-translate

I'm working on a site using bootstrap. Was asked to add google translate on the page. When I added google translate on the page, the google logo appeared twice on select (on mobile) and 1 1/2 arrows beside the logo (on regular screens).

Comment: Do you have some code or fiddle?

Comment: I actually found a fix on this. On css, add #google_translate_element .goog-te-gadget-icon{display:none !important;}